# Get the resource for a specific Rolify role

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorization, rolify

Given that I have a role defined as such:

```
User.first.add_role(:admin, Forum.first)
```

I can determine whether a user has the admin role for any forum with

```
User.first.has_role?(:admin, :any)
```

Is there a way to get at the actual resource that this points to? For instance, in this case, I would get back `Forum.first`, or possibly an array of resources if the User had more than one `:admin` role.

Comment: I solved my issue for now with:
`Forum.find(User.first.roles.where(name: :admin).map(&:resource_id))`, but there is probably a better way so I'll leave the question open

Comment: You should probably mention the associations between the specified models.  If forum belongs to a user and user has many roles. This should work           `user_id = User.first.id`    
`Forum.joins(user: :roles).where('users.id = ? AND roles.name = ?', user_id, 'admin')`

Comment: The second example should be `User.first.has_role?(:admin, Forum)` as `:any` would actually return true if the user has the admin role for any resource not just Forum.

Comment: @max Ah, yes, that makes sense.  In the context of this application, the only resource with the admin role applied is a Forum, so it's the same outcome, but I see why it would be better practice to specify the target resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Forum.with_role(:admin, current_user)
# => [ list of Forum instances that have role "admin" bound to them and belong to current_user roles ]
```

See [resource roles querying](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify#6-resource-roles-querying).